# How to include the prerequisite component 'Windows Installer 3.1' in ClickOnce for user without Internet connection

Tags: visual-studio-2008, clickonce

I'd created a ClickOnce installer.
The prerequisite components of the installer requires:

1. .NET 3.5 SP1
2. Windows Installer 3.1

In order to allow user to install the application WITHOUT any Internet connection, I need to  include the two components into the ClickOnce installer so that user can install it with a CDROM or something.

I'd successfully included the .NET 3.5 SP1 component after some search.
But I can't find anything that talks about way to include 'Windows Installer 3.1' into the installer.

I am using VS2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the needed pre-requsites in the prerequisite window and make sure to

**check**  "Download prereqisite from the same location as my application"

For deatiled information please go through [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx)  url ..you can crack it then.